# Incompatible type error when trying to create a new object

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors

I have a class called Artist where I have created a constructor:

```
public Artist(String artistName)
{
    artistName = artist;
    setupGigs();
    setupBookings();
}
```

In the IO class, I am trying to create a new artist to begin with using the constructor in the Artist class:

```
public GameIO(String nme)
{
    artist = new Artist(nme);
}
```

Each time I compile, I get the error message I am using incompatible types. Should I be doing something different and if so, could someone advise on the best path possible.

Comment: What is artist declared as? Did you try searching for "java incompatible types"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your `artist` is really an `Artist`:

```
private Artist artist;
public GameIO(String nme)
{
    artist = new Artist(nme);
}
```

and not a Piano or String or something else.

```
private String artist; // this won't work
```

Comment: I spent 3 days scared to ask on here! Couldnt figure it out. Thanks for the help. It makes more sense now that I declare it as an Artist in the IO. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome, and I'm glad I could help :) I do agree that this place can be a bit intimidating for beginners, but everyone really is nice and trying to help out! If this ends up solving your problem, don't forget to hit the accept button.